# «Вразлёт» или «в разлёт»?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

[Из статьи о Николае Караченцове] *Он работал, как жил: в полную силу, **в разлёт**, в разбег, на бешеной скорости. Он не умел ходить — он бегал. Не умел входить — вбегал. За минуту до отхода поезда — влетал в вагон на глазах изумленных проводниц и пассажиров.*
М. Райкина. Мы тебя никогда не забудем... МК (Эстония), 31.10.2018

Поначалу я решила, что должно быть слитное написание, потом засомневалась.
Не могу определиться, как правильно — **вразлёт** или **в разлёт**? Подскажите.

**Дополнение**

*...хотелось **жить вразлёт** и наобум,

от птичьих песен просыпаться в девять,

и только день отдав подсчёту сумм,

раздать долги и больше их не делать.*
[Александр Габриэль](https://www.inpearls.ru/599975)

*В какой тональности поет твоя душа,

о чем сыграешь на пороге мира,

как проще **жить, вразлет** иль не спеша?*
[Е. Палашек. Кузнецову](https://www.odessitclub.org/publications/almanac/alm_72/alm_72-213.pdf)

Comment: Рядом с "в разбег" просится и "в разлёт". Только лучше бы порядок изменить.

Answer (score 3):

Вразлет — в разные стороны. Расставив руки и ноги в разные стороны. Здесь явно не это, а скорее имеется в виду разогнавшись, набирать большую скорость в лёте (в словаре есть "с разлета"). И верно подметил @Niemand, тут просится другой порядок перечисления (по возрастающей): в разбег, в разлет.

Comment: *Пойти вразлет — разрушиться.* — Никогда такого не слышал. Вы не путаете с "пойти вразнос"? (В остальном согласен с ответом.)

Comment: @grizzly Мне казалось, это одно и то же. Возможно, это не так.

Answer (score 1):

Вразлет — не подходит, это наречие имеет другое значение. 
ВРАЗЛЁТ, нареч. Разг. **В разные стороны; врозь.** В функции определения. Брови в. (о расходящихся, чуть приподнятых бровях).

В разбег, в разлет  — наречные выражения, близкие **к авторским**.

Существительные "разбег и разлет" могут иметь значение движения с большой скоростью, но наречные выражения, указанные в словаре, — это "с разбега, с разлета".